# Image oveflowing container due to h2 being above it

Tags: html, css

I faced the problem with image overflowing its container when I use height:100%; for the image itself. Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <h2>Website</h2>
    <img src="./images/reptiles.jpg" alt="" > 
  </div>

CSS
div{
height:480px;
}

div>img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 100% means 480px so the total height will be 480px + height of h2 thus the overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif, than k you for your comment and how can I solve img overflow. Only, overflow:hidden or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this html

```
<div>
  <h2>Website</h2>
    <figure>
       <img src="https://www.thalesgroup.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_card/public/database/d7/e-services_modified_1.jpg?itok=DkaYx8h8" alt=""  /> 
    </figure>

  </div>
```

fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/7vxnw95o/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.parent-div{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height:480px;
}

div>img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <h2>Website</h2>
 <div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020315/pexels-photo-1020315.jpeg" alt="" > 
  </div>
</div>
```